# Visual Studio Cordova Android Build error

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, ant

I'm trying to build a cordova project on android. (The project works on windows phone.)

When i try to deploy on the android device, i get :

```
"\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1"
```

Trying to manually run the build.bat, i get a error 2 that i fixed adding the following lines in the ant build.xml:

```
 <property name="aapt" location="${sdk.dir}/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt.exe" />
 <property name="aidl" location="${sdk.dir}/build-tools/22.0.1/aidl.exe" />
 <property name="dx" location="${sdk.dir}/build-tools/22.0.1/dx.bat" />
 <property name="zipalign" location="${sdk.dir}/build-tools/22.0.1/zipalign.exe" />
```

Manually excuting build.bat is working well now, and the apk is created:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 8 seconds
Built the following apk(s):
```

But in visual studio i get the same error : "build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1"

Tried to restart vs2013, and computer and same results.

Do someone knows what's the error about?

Thank you,
Maricel

Comment: I found the problem!  Seems that the phone needed to be developer enabled. And the USB drive installed. (installing kies, installed also the drivers)